# Keep PHP file loaded in memory so that it is not cold starting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, performance, autosuggest

I have a PHP script that generates search suggestions as a user is typing by making an API call with the letters/words the user has currently typed. However, I've noticed that it has some performance issues when a user is typing fast. The script starts lagging behind and the suggestions can't keep up with the pace at which the user is typing. There is a new group of suggestions for each letter that the user types.

If I keep the PHP script always loaded in the server's memory, would this improve its performance? The file is 3kb. Is the script "cold starting" each time its called, and therefore if the user is typing too fast, it begins to lag behind?

Here is the code that calls the PHP script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#searchBox').on('keydown', function(e){
    // get keycode of current keypress event
    var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

    // do nothing if it's an arrow key
    if(code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40) {
        return;
    }

    // do normal behaviour for any other key
    getSuggestions();
    });
});

function getSuggestions(){
    var query = document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#searchSuggestions").load("https://website.com/classes/suggestions.php", {
            q: query
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the PHP script, simplified

```
function get_suggestions ($host, $path, $key, $mkt, $query) {

  *Calls API*
  echo "*Suggestion*";
}
```

What should I do so that the suggestions keep up with what the user is typing? Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Comment: 1. Make sure you're using FastCGI, ideally PHP-FPM, this keeps a PHP _process_ hot and ready to go. 2. Enable Opcache in your PHP config, this keeps your _code_ pre-processed in memory and ready to go.

Comment: The Kernel / PHP runtime are already doing this for you.  Check how long it takes locally; if its slow on your localhost use a profiler like xhprof to figure out what is taking so long.  It is probably network latency or an unoptimized query in the code you simplified out.